# How do I "manage" a HP ProCurve 1400-24G switch?

Tags: networking, switch, managed

I'm confused about my switch. I bought it used so I only have the switch itself, no manuals. I've searched for documentation online and some sources say it's a "managed" switch while others don't state that but also don't say "unmanaged".

1. Is this particular product a "managed" one or not?
2. If it's managed, what does that mean, and how do I then "manage" it?

Comment: Does it have a serial port? most switches capable of management are managed through a console connection (via apps like putty or hyperterminal). Some you will use a cat5/6 cable, sometimes with specialized wiring to connect.

Comment: It's not a managed switch.

Comment: @MaQleod no serial port, but it does have 2 "mini-GBIC slots" (whatever that is) :-)

Comment: mini-gbic are fiber optic modules for higher speed connections, usually to server hardware (storage, vm server, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [HP Document](http://www.hp.com/rnd/pdfs/datasheets/switch_1400_series.pdf), the switches in the 1400 series are unmanaged.

From the PDF:

> The ProCurve Switch 1400 series provides plug-and-play simplicity for
>   high-bandwidth connectivity. The Switch 1400 series consists of two **unmanaged**
>   switches. The ProCurve Switch 1400-24G is a 24-port 10/100/1000 switch with
>   22 10/100/1000 ports and 2 dual-personality ports. The ProCurve Switch
>   1400-8G is a small-form-factor switch with 8 10/100/1000 ports. Ideal for
>   deployment in open spaces, both switches feature silent operation via a fanless
>   design.

[And since you mentioned you didn't have a manual...](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02563672-1%257CdocLocale%253Den_AU&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)

**Managed vs. Unmanaged?**

A managed switch allows you to prioritize connections you as you see fit, giving you the ability to make sure critical network functions take priority.

[Here's a great podcast transcript by Cisco on this topic.](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/switches/networking_solutions_products_genericcontent0900aecd806c7afe.pdf)

Comment: Looks like it's plug 'n' play.

Comment: A datasheet on HP's website. Can't get any better than that - thank you! I wonder why I didn't find that :-/